# $addToSet unable to persist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongo Db and mongoose as the layer. i have a scenario where the like counter should be increment by + 1 only when the user pressing the like button is a new user.

Added this piece of code. Where I am using $addToSet to only have unique values and also using $ set to increment by + 1 if the $addToSet is successful. But the $set is getting executed everytime the update is performed.

Any help would be helpful!!

```
 Posts.update({ _id: postId }, { $addToSet : { thanks : userId}, $set : {likes : postDetails.likes + 1 } }, function (err) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Posts.update({ _id: postId,thanks:{$ne:userId} }, { $push : { thanks : userId}, $inc : {likes : 1 } })
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Shubham,